# How to use my .mo file in the Divi child theme instead of file in a parent /builder directory?

Tags: themes, translation

I use Divi from elegantthemes.com
there is a Lang folder in my parent wordpress theme; I added my own .mo file in the child-theme using load_theme_textdomain.
but there is another file located in /includes/builder/languages parent theme directory. how I can add another .mo file to my child to take effect on this part?
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

its because there was different domain! I added another load_theme_textdomain and it works now.

```
function my_lang_function() {
     load_theme_textdomain( "Divi", get_stylesheet_directory() . "/lang" );
     load_theme_textdomain( "et_builder", get_stylesheet_directory() . "/lang/builder" );
}        
add_action( "after_setup_theme", "my_lang_function" );
```

its my code in function.php of child-theme.
is anything wrong with this code?